# How to export photos in directories named with the dates the photos are taken?

Tags: photos, photos.app, preview

How do I export photos imported from my camera in directories named with the date the photos were taken with built-in Apps?

E.g:

2021-09-01

2021-09-06

2021-09-08

I've done this in the past somehow with either Photos or Preview but now Photos only has a "Moment name" Subfolder Format option.